# The canonical way, if any, of launching a process on Mac OSX if a request comes through on a port?

Tags: macos

I'm working through an interesting Filemaker issue where it's serving up the wrong SSL certificate.

I thought I'd shut down the server to make sure I was working on the right device ... to be sure there wasn't some proxy load balancer in place that I was not aware of.

I shut down the local servers using

`sudo "/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/bin/httpdctl" stop`

on the FileMaker master machine and the FileMaker web worker machine.

I tried to connect using `telnet 127.0.0.1 443` on both devices and sure enough ... no connection. cool.

I tried to connect on `telnet fully.qualified.domain.name 443` and ouch ... I connected.

I checked if any processes were running with `sudo lsof -i ':443'` ... nothing listening.

I've had some experience with linux servers being set up to launch a process if a request comes through on a port.

I'm wondering if there is some other process dynamically listening on port 443 which then opens up apache when a request comes through.

My question is what is the canonical way, if any, of launching a process on Mac OSX if a request comes through on a port?

**Debrief 2019-02-06 04:15:24**

Turned out there was a third machine that was responding to port forwarding rules for ports 80, 443 and 5003.

We used [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to check all the launchd plist files on both machines.

The only items that related to httpd were related to FileMaker.

We removed Filemaker Server from both devices and turned on firewalls and we still got responses on port 80, 443 and 5003 so we were certain we could advise the co-location service provider there was a routing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `launchd`, which is controlled by `launchctl` and certain property list files which describe daemons or agents. Check the man pages for the first two and for `launchd.plist` for the last. Unfortunately, they are no longer online. Also, see [Daemons and Services Programming Guide: Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).